# Pentaho | Centos

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-design-studio, pentaho-data-integration

I am working in Pentaho Data Integretion.
We have developed the transformations and Job in spoon.
We want to move our code on server and server is Centos.

In Centos, we are getting errors while installing UI of Pentaho. We are able to install kitchen on Centos.

Can we run our transformations and job directly with Kitchen?
If yes, how?

Waiting for reply.

Comment: You could start by googling the error messages you get. Or you contact Pentaho customer support.

Comment: will check in google but my question is can we run jobs with kitchen directly without UI installation?

Answer (score 5):

Quoting the docs at

- http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Kitchen+User+Documentation

> Kitchen is a program that can execute jobs designed by Spoon in XML or in a database repository. Usually jobs are scheduled in batch mode to be run automatically at regular intervals.

The docs show examples for running jobs via the `kitchen.sh` script:

> This example runs a job from file on a windows platform:
>
> ```
> kitchen.bat /file:D:\Jobs\updateWarehouse.kjb /level:Basic
> ```
>
> This example runs a job from file on a Linux box:
>
> ```
> kitchen.sh -file=/PRD/updateWarehouse.kjb -level=Minimal
> ```
>
> This example runs a job from the repository on a windows platform:
>   (Enter on a single line without returns...)
>
> ```
> kitchen.bat
>                 /rep:"Production Repository"
>                 /job:"Update dimensions"
>                 /dir:/Dimensions
>                 /user:matt
>                 /pass:somepassword123
>                 /level:Basic
> ```

So I'd say the answer is yes, it's possible to run your transformations and job directly with Kitchen.

Answer (score 1):

if you  have to run transformations and jobs using kitchen or pan commands, then there is no need to install the Pentaho, just download the zip file and unzip  on centos machine. you have set the JAVA_HOME environmental variable

Comment: That's the way to go.
With one more trick: you can have a kettle.property file on your machine and another on the CentOS server. So if you write your transformations/jobs with stuff like ${property} in connections, passwords,... they will be automagically translated when you copy the transfo/job from your dev-machine to the prod-CentOS.
A brilliant idea of Matt Casters and Jens Bleuel.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Carte on centos. 
http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Carte+User+Documentation

So you start carte server and run your jobs and transformations at this carte server.